# Зачем нужны ветки?

Tags: git, git-branch

Зачем нужны ветки в git?

Можно ли обойтись без них?

Как я могу их использовать?

Comment: За что минусуют-то такие вопросы?

Comment: Минусаторы обычно не объявляются.

Comment: @Etki, а этот вопрос разве чем-то хорош? Человек ленится просто прочитать тонны информации с примерами на эту тему, вопрос не конкретный а общий, на него можно ответ дать "мои дофаминовые рецепторы каждый раз радостно пищат, когда я набираю `git branch newbranch` в консоли!" (говоря по-русски - я тащусь, когда создаю новую ветку). 

А похожим вопросом может быть "зачем буква "д" в русском языке, расскажите побольше о ситуациях, где без нее не обойтись" (интересно, если на РЯ такой вопрос задать, заминусуют или будут серьезно отвечать).

Comment: @eicto, вопрос и не обязан быть хорошим. И это не стандартный "как мне прочитать файл средствами php", на который есть четкий ответ, записанный в документации - этот вопрос носит слегка философский характер, и автор может прочесть хоть сотню раз про гит-флоу, но так и не понять, почему ему это выгодней, чем держать все в одной ветке; в интернете обычно пишут, **как** делать, а не **зачем**. Да ему и вправду может быть удобней в одной ветке держать, вот он и спрашивает. ->

Comment: Может, думает, что что-то упускает и надо бы об этом спросить. Это вообще не имеет разницы.

На РЯ это было бы "зачем нужны деепричастные обороты". И, опять же, это был бы вопрос "как я их могу использовать?", а не "какую функцию выполняет".

Comment: > вопрос и не обязан быть хорошим. 
ну я тупой робот - если вопрос не хороший - он плохой, следовательно я ставлю минус (а за что ещё минусы ставить?)

Comment: Вот [пункт, под который попадает вопрос](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#explicit)

>  Так, например, вопрос: "Можете ли вы дать мне ссылку на хорошее описание X?" - обычно куда разумнее, чем просьба: "Объясните мне X, пожалуйста". Если у вас проблема с неработающим кодом, разумнее будет попросить объяснить, что в нем не так, а не просить исправить ошибки.

Я как бы не сверяю всё с этим мануалом, просто 90% вопросов, которые кажутся мне плохими, описаны здесь.

Comment: Я также не минусую вопросы, которые частично попадают под ошибки, описанные в этом документе, но содержат также и какие-то хорошие части, обычно это касается вопросов с самоунижением, в таких случаях я просто ставлю ссылку на пункт мануала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Классическая модель репы:

master - последний стабильный релиз ; 
dev - текущая ветка разработки;
dev-xxx - отпочковавшаяся ветка разработки, связанная с планируемым в далеком будущем релизом.

2 - Классическая работа в командной репе:

слил обновления - отпочковал ветку - работаешь в ней - доделал - снова слил обновления в оригинальную ветку - слил ветки - запустил в общую репу.

3 - Т.н. git-flow - каждый багфикс и фича оформляются в отдельную ветку, после конца работы происходит слияние с dev-веткой, в остальном работа как в пункте 1, плюс-минус тонкости отпочковывания хотфиксов и их мержей. [Ссылка раз](http://sitedev.ru/git-flow/), [ссылка два](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147260/).

Comment: А зачем нужен пункт 2-то? В гите с этим проще - коммитишть себе локально, а когда собрался залить все в центральный репозиторий, делаешь git pull и git rebase, и твои коммиты встают после последнего коммита в мастере на сервере. Коллизии и с отдельной веткой все равно возникнут, если есть.

Comment: @aknew, слияния тоже ребейзом на ура делаются. Дело просто в изоляции, в том, что можно спокойно делать пулл основной ветки, не боясь сразу нарваться на конфликт.

Answer (score 5):

При помощи веток в VCS можно:

- Реализовать фичу, не мешая остальным.
- Проводить модерацию (кодревью) нового кода перед непосредственным добавлением в кодовую базу.
- Отвлечься от реализации фичи и починить баг в другом месте.
- Вовсе отложить начатую фичу до лучших времен.
- Получить запрос на доработку старой версии программы от заказчика и поддерживать далее несколько версий ПО.
- Поэкспериментировать с кодом без страха сломать билд.
- Организовать процесс поэтапного выпуска программы (разработка - тестирование - релиз), не блокируя разработку следующей версии.
- Организовать работу с open source сообществом или подрядчиком.
- Запилить постоянную автоматическую сборку с рабочей ветки с прогоном тестов и ручную авторизованную сборку релиза с релиз-ветки.

В случае с гитом сама распределенная работа неразрывно связана с понятием локальных и удаленных веток и синхронизацией коммитов между ними.

Answer (score 0):

Ветка в Git'е — это просто «скользящий» указатель на один из коммитов. Когда вы создаёте новые коммиты, указатель ветки автоматически сдвигается вперёд, к вновь созданному коммиту.

Для работы с Git на самом простом проекте с одним разработчиком бывает достаточно одной ветки, но на более крупных проектах используется более одной ветки. Существуют различные стратегии управления ветками, такие как [git-flow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-flow/info).

В принципе, можно обойтись без веток, создавая все коммиты вручную, после чего они будут храниться, как потерянные объекты. Но это - неоправданно сложный способ. К тому же, сборщик мусора рано или поздно их удалит.